# Run Through Column A Removing Four Characters From The Right

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run through ranges `A2:LastRow` and trim the right side of the cell by four characters (e.g. `"06/19/2018 Tue"` to `"06/19/2018"`).

I tried:

```
Dim trim_date As String

row_number2 = 1
Do
    DoEvents
    row_number2 = row_number + 1
    trim_date = Sheets("Data_TC").Range("A" & row_number2)
    trim_date = Right(Sheets("Data_TC").Range("A" & row_number2), 4)

Loop Until row_number2 = LastRow(ActiveSheet)
```

Comment: I was trying the loop below but running into issues with it - means nothing.  No one but you knows the issues you are running into.  Try to be a bit more detailed about the issue, what is expected, what is happening.

Comment: you could just do `trim_date = Trim(Left(Sheets("Data_TC").Range("A" & row_number2), InStr(1, Sheets("Data_TC").Range("A" & row_number2), " ", vbTextCompare)))`

Comment: My apologies- incredibly new to VBA. Essentially I am trying to create a loop that will run through a given range and remove the four last characters of each cell

Answer (score 1):

Try this sub that will be faster as it doesn't require a loop:

Option Explicit

```
Sub trim4()

    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Set dataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_TC")

    With dataSheet

        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        'stage trimmed values
        .Range(.Cells(1, .Columns.Count), .Cells(lastRow, .Columns.Count)).FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[-" & .Columns.Count - 1 & "],LEN(RC[-" & .Columns.Count - 1 & "])-4)"

        'set trimmed values
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 1)).Value = .Range(.Cells(1, .Columns.Count), .Cells(lastRow, .Columns.Count)).Value

        'clear stage
        .Range(.Cells(1, .Columns.Count), .Cells(lastRow, .Columns.Count)).ClearContents

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like as follows (though an array would be faster)

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    With Worksheets("Data_TC"")
        For Each rng In .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
          If Len(rng.Value) >= 4 Then rng.Value = Left$(rng.Value, Len(rng.Value) - 4)
        Next rng
    End With
End Sub
```

---

As array

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim arr(), i As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        arr = .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
          If Len(arr(i, 1)) >= 4 Then arr(i, 1) = Left$(arr(i, 1), Len(arr(i, 1)) - 4)
        Next i
        .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
    End With
End Sub
```